# Find a random method that best fit list of values

Tags: python, random, statistics

I have a list of many float numbers, representing the length of an operation made several times.

For each type of operation, I have a different trend in numbers.

I'm aware of many random generators presented in some python modules, like in numpy.random

For example, I have `binomial`, `exponencial`, `normal`, `weibul`, and so on...

I'd like to know if there's a way to find the best `random generator`, given a list of values, that best fit each list of numbers that I have.

I.e, the generator (with its params) that best fit the trend of the numbers on the list

That's because I'd like to automatize the generation of time lengths, of each operation, so that I can simulate it during `n` years, without having to find by hand what method fits best what list of numbers.

**EDIT:** In other words, trying to clarify the problem:

I have a list of numbers. I'm trying to find the probability distribution that best fit the array of numbers I already have. The only problem I see is that each probability distribution has input params that may interfer on the result. So I'll have to figure out how to enter this params automatically, trying to best fit the list.

Any idea?

Comment: Using a random number generator for this is even worse than making ungrounded, outragous extrapolation (as seen in http://xkcd.com/605/). Y'know, it's (pseudo-)random. Even if the first hundred numbers for a given seed match your data exactly, the 101th and the 102nd might be completely wrong in completely different ways.

Comment: @delnan But is there a way to find a best random generator that fits the list? Because I think that, trending to infinite, the generator will fits better my trend. Any idea?

Comment: Also, I only have the time length. This is not a 2 dimensional list, I just have the time.

Comment: Well, of course you can try each generator a few times with different seeds and compare the generated values with the ones you have. But again, this doesn't mean *anything* about the trend of future values (unless of course the PRNG is so completely broken that it doesn't deserve that label). It seems you rather want to check the trends of the data manually, then extrapolate from that.

Comment: @delnan Hey life. That's what I was trying to automatize. I was wanting to check the trend of the data automatically. So, there's no good way, right?

Comment: Perhaps you can recognize some common patterns (always within a certain range, growing with a certain factor, etc.) automatically and generate generators (and in, uses `yield`) that have a similar trend continued ad infinitum - viola, basic extrapolation. But in general, my guess is no.

Comment: @delnan thank you for the fast help. Please, if possible, post this as an answer, so that I can accept in the end of the day.

Comment: I'm not sure how the first sentence and the rest of the question are related, to be honest. I'm sure there's a perfectly sensible way to model execution times of a program, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Gabriel L. Oliveira Considering that delnan and I have interpreted your question quite differently, you might want to reword your question to clarify what sort of trends you're looking for.

Comment: @Michael @delnan I added more info, but my question is closer to what you are thinking Michael

Answer (score 3):

You might find it better to think about this in terms of probability distributions, rather than thinking about random number generators. You can then think in terms of testing goodness of fit for your different distributions.

As a starting point, you might try constructing [probability plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_plot) for your samples. Probably the easiest in terms of the math behind it would be to consider a [Q-Q plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Q_plot). Using the random number generators, create a sample of the same size as your data. Sort both of these, and plot them against one another. If the distributions are the same, then you should get a straight line.

**Edit:** To find appropriate parameters for a statistical model, [maximum likelihood estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) is a standard approach. Depending on how many samples of numbers you have and the precision you require, you may well find that just playing with the parameters by hand will give you a "good enough" solution.

Comment: I'll try this. And joining both ideas, maybe I can calculate the sum of standard deviation of each type of probability distribution, so that I can choose the better one. What you think? The only problem I see is that each probability distribution has input params that change the trend of the probability distribution.

Comment: @Gabriel, if you take the distributions you mentioned and use them analytically, you can fit for all of their "enter" parameters, assuming you have enough data points.

Comment: @Gabriel juanchopanza is definitely right that you can do this analytically for known distributions - I mentioned a Q-Q plot only because it's easier to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Why using random numbers for this is a bad idea has already been explained. It seems to me that what you really need is to fit the distributions you mentioned to your points (for example, with a least squares fit), then check which one fits the points best (for example, with a chi-squared test).

**EDIT** Adding reference to [numpy least squares fitting example](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-ef374c752c3530b09022336de9adc2ce85af822c)

Comment: thank you to contribute. I'll study this alternative to understand it better, so that I can use it. As soon as I get news, I'll come back here. Thank you all @delnan @Michael @juanchopanza for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Given a parameterized univariate distirbution (e.g. [exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) depends on lambda, or [gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) depends on theta and k), the way to find the parameter values that best fit a given sample of numbers is called the [Maximum Likelyhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) procedure. It is not a least squares procedure, which would require binning and thus loosing information! Some Wikipedia distribution articles give expressions for the maximum likelyhood estimates of parameters, but many do not, and even the ones that do are missing expressions for error bars and covarainces. If you know calculus, you can derive these results by expressing the log likeyhood of your data set in terms of the parameters, setting the second derivative to zero to maximize it, and using the inverse of the curvature matrix at the minimum as the covariance matrix of your parameters.

Given two different fits to two different parameterized distributions, the way to compare them is called the [likelyhood ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test). Basically, you just pick the one with the larger log likelyhood.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel, if you have access to `Mathematica`, parameter estimation is built in:

```
In[43]:= data = RandomReal[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10]

Out[43]= {1.55598, 0.375999, 0.0878202, 1.58705, 0.874423, 2.17905, \
0.247473, 0.599993, 0.404341, 0.31505}

In[44]:= EstimatedDistribution[data, ExponentialDistribution[la], 
 ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]

Out[44]= ExponentialDistribution[1.21548]

In[45]:= EstimatedDistribution[data, ExponentialDistribution[la], 
 ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]

Out[45]= ExponentialDistribution[1.21548]
```

However, it might be easy to figure what maximum likelihood method commands the parameter to be.

```
In[48]:= Simplify[
 D[LogLikelihood[ExponentialDistribution[la], {x}], la], x > 0]

Out[48]= 1/la - x
```

Hence the estimated parameter for exponential distribution is `sum (1/la -x_i)` from where `la = 1/Mean[data]`. Similar equations can be worked out for other distribution families and coded in the language of your choice.